# jQuery - Hover over one element to change two different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a website that features a grid of images, with a simple text box to the right.  Within the box are a h3 and p element.  When hovering over a specific image, I'd like the h3 and p to change.  Currently the h3 changes without issue, however the p text will only change when the mouse leaves said image.

The website:  https://crux.baker.edu/~evolme01/responsive%20web%20test/home.html

Hover over the first image for example to the top left.  The h3 will change to EYES WIDE SHUT, but the p text will only change when you mouse out.  The same happens when you hover over the header.  How can I get them both to change at the same time?

The relevant HTML:

```
<div id="grid">

    <div class="grid-element" id="ews">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/ews.jpg"/></a>
        <span></span>
    </div>
```

---

```
   <div class="right-content">
            <h3>THE KUBRICK CORNER</h3>
                <p>This website deals with exploring the works of Stanley Kubrick, one of the most widely praised yet continuously misunderstood film directors of the 20th century.
                If you wish to submit an article, please email me at tieman64@hotmail.com. All submissions are welcomed. Thank you to everyone who has contributed.
        </p>
            </div>
```

The relevant CSS:

```
#grid{
 width: 450px;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

 }

.grid-element {
     width:132px;
     height: 132px;
     float:left;
     /*padding: 0px 50px 25px 0px;*/

 }

.grid-element img {
     width:126px;
     height: 126px;
     opacity: 1;
     border: 5px solid rgba(255 ,255 ,255 ,0.5);
      }

      .grid-element img:hover {
      }
```

---

```
.right-content {
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
    height: 255px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 65px;
    display: block;
    font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.right-content h3 {

    text-align: center;
    margin:0px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.right-content p {

    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: smaller;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

How I'm doing it with jQuery:

```
$('.grid-element#ews').hover( function() { 
   $('.right-content h3').text("EYES WIDE SHUT");
} , function() { 
   $('.right-content p').text("After Dr. Bill Hartford's wife, Alice, admits to having sexual fantasies about a man she met, Bill becomes obsessed with having a sexual encounter. He discovers an underground sexual group and attends one of their meetings -- and quickly discovers that he is in over his head.");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it instead like this. I tried this in the `console`:

```
$('.grid-element#ews').hover( function() { 
   $('.right-content h3').text("EYES WIDE SHUT");
   $('.right-content p').text("After Dr. Bill Hartford's wife, Alice, admits to having sexual fantasies about a man she met, Bill becomes obsessed with having a sexual encounter. He discovers an underground sexual group and attends one of their meetings -- and quickly discovers that he is in over his head.");
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  This solved it.  Thought it had to be separated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put them together?

```
$('.grid-element#ews').hover( function() { 
   $('.right-content h3').text("EYES WIDE SHUT");
   $('.right-content p').text("After Dr. Bill Hartford's wife, Alice, admits to having sexual fantasies about a man she met, Bill becomes obsessed with having a sexual encounter. He discovers an underground sexual group and attends one of their meetings -- and quickly discovers that he is in over his head.");
});
```